# Внедрение логгирования в вызов функции

Tags: javascript, typescript

Настраиваю логгер у себя в проекте, мне нужно отследить все действия связанные с буфером, например.
Первое, что приходит в голову, это следующий код:

```ts
Buffer.alloc = (...args) => {
  log(`Buffer allocated!`)
  return Buffer.alloc(...args)
}
```

Что естественно вызовет переполнение стека.

Другой способ работает, но он достаточно муторный и требует танцев с бубнами над **TypeScript**

```ts
Buffer.alloc = 
(arg1, arg2, arg3, logged: boolean) => { // <-- Implicit any + [signature] is not assignable...
  if(logged) return
  log()
  return Buffer.alloc(arg1, arg2, arg3, true)
}
```

Хочется чего-то вроде

```ts
inject(Buffer.alloc, size => log(`Allocating buffer with ${size} size`))
```

Comment: чтобы первый вариант сработал, достаточно сохранить старое значение в переменную и потом ее использовать: `var a = Buffer.alloc; Buffer.alloc = (...args) => { log(...); a(...args)}`

Comment: @Grundy Похоже на правду. А с типизацийе проблем не будет? Мне кажется `...args` не сработает, нужно будет все аргументы вручную писать

Comment: попробуй ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ну и типы всегда можно взять из старого значения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришёл к такому **TypeScript-friendly** решению.

```ts
const inject = <T extends (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T>, P extends Parameters<T>>(target: T, cb: (meta, ...args: P) => void): T => {
  const metadata = {
    /* e.g. stacktrace */
  }
  return ((...args: P) => {
    cb(metadata, ...args)
    return target(...args)
  }) as T
}

Buffer.alloc = inject(Buffer.alloc, (meta, size) => console.log(`Allocating buffer with ${size} bytes`))

Buffer.alloc(128) // Allocating buffer with 128 bytes
Buffer.alloc(256) // Allocating buffer with 256 bytes
```